# access shared Google Calendar without entering userid/password

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have a google calendar that I have marked as shared.  it stores all appointments for the day.

I have a webpage. from the webpage, the user enters a date and I use the google api (javascript) to pull back all info from my shared calendar for that date and present it to the user.

I also want the user to be able to make appointments during free times on any given day.

problem is, I must be signed in to my google account.  if I am NOT signed in, I get a little popup asking for my userid/password.

how do I get rid of that?  I had hoped that making the calendar shared and specifying the client ID and api key (assigned via Google's API  Console) would have been enough.

I've run across this:  http://cornempire.net/2012/01/08/part-2-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/  which explains doing this via Oath and refresh tokens in PHP.

unfortunately, I'm doing this in javascript and MUST do it from the client side.  is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into using a service acccount for this.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

By using a service account you wont have to worry about people loging in. They will have access to the calender for the service account.

---

Update:  I have searched for examples of how to do this in Javascript and have been unable to find any.   After considering this issue for a while now i have come to the conculsiton that even if you could use a service account via javascript for security reasons its probably not a good idea.

Unfortuantly this leaves me to beleave that the anwser to your question is No.  You cant do this client sided.  If you use normal OAuth2 its still going to prompt you for the autentication.  You need to try and reconsider a server sidded option.  PHP for example

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.  i thought a service account may be the right way to go.  the documentation link mentions server-to-server and PHP.  do you know if its possible to access a service account via Javascript running in a browser?

Comment: you should be able to.  The code isnt all that diffrent then the code to access it normaly.

Comment: hate to be a pest, but do you have any links or references about how to use a service account to get access to a google calendar via javascript?  i've created a service account but am unsure how to set up the javascript.